# Too many threads being created in Windows Service - How can I tell what is creating them?

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, logging, windows-services

Is there a way in my service code to log each time a thread is being created and what is causing it and maybe some info about it like its ID?

I have a complex windows service that is doing several jobs including communicating via web sockets, sending/receiving UDP messages to/from various network devices, interfacing with USB objects, talking to an unreal engine, hosting a REST API, and communicating via JSON RPC.

The problem I'm seeing is that occasionally (not often), everything will lock, and I can't do anything on the machine until I restart the service. Looking at the minidump, I think the problem is that there are WAY too many threads being created, but I can't see who owns them or what is spinning them up.

I have some suspicions that most of the threads are being created by some of the UDP processes, and maybe when it doesn't get the responses it's waiting for via UDP (I know UDP doesn't send responses and isn't meant for this but I can't change how this smart devices is sending and receiving messages), but I have no way of knowing.

Comment: use log4net and log everything...

Comment: Also, make sure you set the `Thread.Name` property at least in the code you control:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If the issues is likely a trhead waiting for network activity, how about a timeout? A timeout would be a good idea with or without this issue, so it might be worth doing on a chance.

Comment: Also, as other general advice for this situation, sometimes you can remove many locks and potential points of contention by having multiple threads put actions (Delegates, as the simplest example) in a single-threaded queue.  For example, only one thread could be allowed to send UDP messages.  Other threads would simply make this request to that thread:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Great comments everyone, thanks - I've gone through and named a bunch of threads and that will help narrow it down I think. What about for external dependencies? For example, we actually interface with another library that manages our RPC communication - is there a way to see when that library that I don't have control over is creating threads and what is creating them?

Comment: I had same problem, this tool was very useful for me, I hope it will be useful for you too: [Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2895198/debug-diagnostics-tool-v2-0-is-now-available)

Comment: `I think the problem is that there are WAY too many threads being created` Please define how much is "way too many". Also, if it locks the entire machine you should look at the number of handles for the process (you can add that column in the task manager). What you're describing is often a sign of leaking handles (threads use handles, so the two issues could be correlated)